# Does Chromecast support aspx type receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I tried to implement a receiver.aspx application but the device can't open it properly.

It could be my mistake or the chromecast doesn't support the aspx file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only supports html (+ JavaScript and CSS).

Comment: Thank you very much! But if I know well, the sender applicaton could be any type of web application? (aspx, silverlight, etc.)

Comment: Are you talking about the sender or receiver? Your original post is about receiver and in your comment you mention sender. On the receiver, it can only be html5 web page. On the sender, we have SDK for Chrome, iOS and Android.

Comment: I have an asp.net web pages web site (it contains a Silverlight player which plays the video). It's the sender (it could be a sender becouse I used the API) and the receiver is an asp.net web pages site too, (it uses the Receiver API and Media Player Library API). So therefore I could use an asp.net web pages site as a chromecast receiver and sender as well. So it couldn't be a problem in this case.

Comment: What technology is used to create HTML pages is up to you, receiver needs to load an HTML page, so as long as the URL you set for your receiver returns an HTML page, you should be fine.